# How can I toggle CSS using Angular and Ionic?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am building an app using Ionic and Angular. I have the following code as per [design layout given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYRhf.png).

```
<div id ="neededfoodnames" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index">

  <ion-item (click)="togglefoods(list.category)" *ngIf="lists[i-1]?.category != list.category" class="categoryList">
    {{list.category}}
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-forward" *ngIf="list.category != currentCategory"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-down" *ngIf="list.category == currentCategory"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>

<div class="foodList" *ngIf="list.category == currentCategory" (click)="unlist(list)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          We Need
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="offFoods">
          {{list.foodname}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  class="onFoods">
          {{list.foodname}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</div>
</div>
```

I have foods in a Firebase database with the following structure:

```
    {
  "category" : "Meat",
  "foodname" : "Chicken",
  "state" : "on"
}
```

How can I create a CSS toggle for the additem(list) and unlist(list) events so that the object is grayed out if it is present in the other column (or grey it out based on it's "state"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ngClass` to dynamically add the css class you want that has the desired styles to apply based on the 'state: on/off' value.

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="offFoods" [ngClass]="{'grey-out': list.state !== 'on'}">
      {{list.foodname}}
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col  class="onFoods" [ngClass]="{'grey-out': list.state !== 'on'}">
      {{list.foodname}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Then define your css for the class `.grey-out { color: gray; // or whatever color you choose }` accordingly in the styles.